What should I call my graduated PhD advisee?
How should a PhD advisor refer to their PhD advisee after successfully defending and graduating?  "Former PhD advisee" sounds like it didn't end well.  "PhD alumnus" sounds too vague.
Any suggestions?

I suggest using the "in-science" extended family analogy, so they are your son/daughter/child in-science and you are their father/mother/parent in-science :)

"former student"?

Colleague. Isn't that the point of a PhD program?

For what purpose are you referring to them?  Dr. XXX seems like a reasonable answer for many situations.  Are you introducing them at a talk?  Then Dr. XXX seems reasonable, with some more words about them being your student (who made good).  In cocktail party chatter, my student Dr. XXX might work.  I think there are many answers depending on the situation.

@RossMillikan Clearly we are talking about a context where we want to convey that they were our former PhD student

The family metaphor is common, at least in math and computer science. See The Mathematics Genealogy for example. I’d offer something like my academic offspring.

"advisee" is too awkward a construction.  It maybe semantically correct, but it's still not in use.  While it may seem like it's just symmetrical to "advisor", its usage is not.  "My former student" is sufficient.  While it may seem important to emphasize that you advised them on their dissertation, in the long term, their PhD defines them, or doesn't, on its own.  "Former student" is enough to communicate that you significantly contributed to their academic development.

"Doctor" should do

I've most often seen the simple 'my former PhD-student'. If from context it is clear they now have a PhD (because they are postdocs/ lecturer/ professors themselves) there is no ambiguity about the success of their PhD in practice. Theoretically they could have failed as your PhD student and then gotten a PhD elsewhere but I think this situation is sufficiently rare that no one would assume that without further context.

I agree 100%. This is a very natural-sounding phrase, and most people pass so it is not necessary to make a clumsy phrase that includes that fact.

"Former PhD student" is definitely the correct answer. Just like "former advisor" is the answer for the reverse direction.

If you give their title as part of their name then it sounds like success rather than otherwise. Dr. K. Smith, a former advisee.
Former successful advisee also works.
This assumes you are speaking of them to third parties. When speaking to them directly you have presumably worked out how you refer to each other. But calling them "Doctor" is a nice touch.
I once called a recently promoted colleague "Professor" strongly stressing the word. She gave a big smile.

"Dr. K Smith, my graduated student" works, too.

Would not "Dr. K. Smith, my student" generally work as well?

@JonCuster, depending on context, perhaps. Of course, Dr. K. may have earned a previous doctorate, even medical.

Most of these sound terrible. I can't imagine anyone saying the word advisee and it sounding natural.

@BryanKrause "Graduated" as an adjective has a totally different meaning from as a verb. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/graduated

@toby544 I've heard it used with exactly the same meaning as the verb, too.

It's in the title. What's wrong with "graduated PhD advisee"? It implies success, and that you were their advisor for the PhD.

It is a very clumsy-sounding phrase

Dr. Last Name. They have earned their doctorate. They are are now a Doctor of whatever it is they graduated in. In formal settings this entitles them to to be called Dr. Last Name.
Do universities no longer teach etiquette?
If you want to introduce your relationship to them as well. "Please meet  my former student Dr. Last Name(protegee, mentee, etc...) " works. Shows the relationship, and that they earned their PhD (hence doctor). Though after they have had their degree for a couple of years this is bad form on your part.

We are talking about a short phrase to convey that they were our former PhD student. Nobody is suggesting that we should say this every time we mention their name for the rest of our lives.
